# Definition and location of jpos.xml JavaPos

Tags: javapos

I am trying to write a hello world application that prints through JavaPos into an Epson TM-T20 printer. Every example I find talks about a jpos.xml file. What does this file look like? Where can I get an example of such file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Download developer's CD image from https://download.epson-biz.com/ for appropriate family of printers. It contains JavaPoS. JavaPoS contains SetupPOS wizard for composing jpos.xml for Epson printers.
I downloaded it recently and it was tricky. 1stly, it is downloaded through SSL so I can't use any download manager, just browser. 2ndly, last bytes of archive are not received, so it's corrupted so I could uncompress the archive with zip repairer only.